# What is the name of this school?

Tags: identify-this, bangkok

What is the name of this school in Bangkok, Thailand? This picture was taken in 1972.

[image: Cub Scout Event]

Comment: This question does not appear to have any clear connection to traveling.

Comment: If it's in either Bangkok, it looks like an international school.

Comment: Why is this question off-topic and all the other 'where is this picture taken?' questions not?

Comment: VTC: too broad: it is likely that this is not a school, but a group of US family and dependents: the children appear to be Cub Scouts, the woman at front is in a female scout uniform (and an adult male in Boy Scout uniform), and there is a person in US military fatigues. As it was 1972, it suggests they may be at an embassy or military compound and without additional details, almost impossible to identify (especially since the presence of US military and family in Thailand ended by the mid-70's). OP has not returned since asking the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with travel.